# How do you collect bug reports for a published android app

Tags: android

To collect crash reports as a developer one uses logcat. Is there a standard way for a published android application to capture crash logs so that your users can send them to you?

Is there any callback that is called when an app crashes for example? Can the strategy that logcat uses to log be adopted to a production game?

Similar question for iOS Apps:
[How can I allow users to give me feedback and submit bug reports for my iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917047/how-can-i-allow-users-to-give-me-feedback-and-submit-bug-reports-for-my-ios-app)

Related Question
[How can I accept bug reports and other user feedback from within my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942771/how-can-i-accept-bug-reports-and-other-user-feedback-from-within-my-app)

**EDIT 1:**
In addition to the frameworks mentioned in the answers below a lower level approach to capturing all uncaught exceptions can be used an is mentioned here [Ideal way to set global uncaught exception Handler in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764394/ideal-way-to-set-global-uncaught-exception-handler-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally use [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/). I found it easy to integrate, and it meets my requirements.

Reports are sent to a spreadsheet in Google Docs, and it can be configured to send you an email every time the app crashes

Comment: in your experience does Acra cause any performance degradation?

Answer (score 2):

Using logcat is a solution but is only feasible when crashes are coming from your own device. However, you can have the crashes occurring on your users’ devices automatically sent to you as well, including all crash and device details.
This could be done through [Instabug](https://instabug.com) which is a bug & crash reporting service.
It automatically sends a report containing all crash and device details once a crash occurs, plus It only takes a line of code to integrate in your app.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can include [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/) in your app, which does create an error log when something craches and sends in back to the server, which you have access to. It will give you all the information like the LogCat.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is also FirebaseCrash by Google which reports logs on your Firebase console.
Read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android)

The Google Play Developer Console also reports crashes and application not responsive, under crashes and ANRs for each app.